# How to change system fonts list in Firefox to avoid browser fingerprinting?

Tags: firefox, browser-extensions, fingerprinting, tracking

I found solution for most of types of browser fingerprints:

- IP - ZenMate Firefox VPN Add-on
- Canvas - CanvasBlocker Add-on
- Timezone - I use AutoIt to change Windows Timezone
- List of PlugIns - I just disable them all
- HTTP Headers - Random Agent Spoofer Add-on
- Screen Size - dc.exe -width=640 -height=480 -refresh=60
- List of Fonts - I did disable flash detection, but still I have a 57/1 list of fonts https://panopticlick.eff.org. Is it possible to change this list programmatically ? Thank you.

Comment: This will answer your question exactly: http://superuser.com/questions/292666/how-to-disable-permission-to-read-system-fonts-and-browser-plugin-details-in

Comment: Despite the fact you have wrapped the question up in amongst that other data, this question is "how do I change fonts" - off topic here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I think the question is asking how to configure the browser to surf anonymously. That seems on topic to me

Comment: Have you looked at the Tor browser? That comes pre-configured for anonymity